# Flutter: How to clear chart data?

Tags: flutter, charts, flutter-dependencies, flutter-widget

I'm trying to build an app in flutter with a chart that updates every 30 seconds with the latest data from a website. The chart is displayed correctly at first but when the new data is added to chart without replacing the previous one so that with time more and more lines are shown. I've tried many ways but I always get the same result. In the code I'm using fl_animated_linechart but I got the same result with charts_flutter.
Can you please help me?

Code in main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'chart.dart';
import 'package:fl_animated_linechart/fl_animated_linechart.dart';

final Map<DateTime, double> dataSet = {};
final Map<DateTime, double> dataRec = {};

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: Home(),
));

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  ChartWidget chartWidget;

  double set_temp = 18.0;
  double rec_temp = 15.0;

  String get_url = 'url';
  String post_url = 'url';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
    Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 30), (time) async {
      fetchData();
    });
  }

  void fetchData() async{

    Response response = await get(get_url);
    List data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(response.body);
    setState(() {
      set_temp = double.parse(data[9]['setTemperature']);
      rec_temp = double.parse(data[9]['recTemperature']);
      for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
        dataSet[DateTime.parse(data[i]['date'])] = double.parse(data[i]['setTemperature']);
        dataRec[DateTime.parse(data[i]['date'])] = double.parse(data[i]['recTemperature']);
      }

    });

  }

  void sendData() async{
    Response response = await post(post_url, body: {'tempSet': set_temp.toString()});
    print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
    print('Response body: ${response.body}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'TERMOSMART'
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 40.0,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 200.0,
                  child: chartWidget,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
      )
    );
  }
}

class ChartWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChartWidgetState createState() => _ChartWidgetState();
}

class _ChartWidgetState extends State<ChartWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Chart(dataSet: dataSet, dataRec: dataRec);
  }
}
```

Code in chart.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fl_animated_linechart/fl_animated_linechart.dart';


class Chart extends StatefulWidget {

  Map<DateTime, double> dataRec = {};
  Map<DateTime, double> dataSet = {};

  Chart({this.dataRec, this.dataSet});

  @override
  _ChartState createState() => _ChartState();

}

class _ChartState extends State<Chart> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    LineChart chart;
    chart = LineChart.fromDateTimeMaps(
        [widget.dataRec, widget.dataSet],
        [Colors.green, Colors.blue],
        ['C', 'C']);

    return  Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: AnimatedLineChart(
            chart,
            key: UniqueKey(),
          ), //Unique key to force animations
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
I use random number to simulate this case 
You can use `dataSet.clear();` and `dataRec.clear();` to remove old data;

```
setState(() {         
      dataSet.clear();
      dataRec.clear();
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var now = DateTime.now();
        print(i);
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber1 = random.nextInt(100);
        int randomNumber2 = random.nextInt(100);
        dataSet[now.add(Duration(days: i))] = randomNumber1.toDouble();
        dataRec[now.add(Duration(days: i))] = randomNumber2.toDouble();
      }
    });
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:fl_animated_linechart/fl_animated_linechart.dart';
import 'dart:math';

final Map<DateTime, double> dataSet = {};
final Map<DateTime, double> dataRec = {};

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    ));

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  ChartWidget chartWidget;

  double set_temp = 18.0;
  double rec_temp = 15.0;

  String get_url = 'url';
  String post_url = 'url';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   /* WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
      fetchData();
    });*/
    fetchData();

    Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 3), (time) async {
      fetchData();
    });
  }

  void fetchData() async {
    /*Response response = await get(get_url);
    List data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(response.body);*/
    setState(() {
      /*set_temp = double.parse(data[9]['setTemperature']);
      rec_temp = double.parse(data[9]['recTemperature']);*/
      dataSet.clear();
      dataRec.clear();
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var now = DateTime.now();
        print(i);
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber1 = random.nextInt(100);
        int randomNumber2 = random.nextInt(100);
        dataSet[now.add(Duration(days: i))] = randomNumber1.toDouble();
        dataRec[now.add(Duration(days: i))] = randomNumber2.toDouble();
      }
    });
  }

  /*void sendData() async {
    Response response =
        await post(post_url, body: {'tempSet': set_temp.toString()});
    print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
    print('Response body: ${response.body}');
  }
*/
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('TERMOSMART'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 40.0,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 200.0,
                child: ChartWidget(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )));
  }
}

class ChartWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChartWidgetState createState() => _ChartWidgetState();
}

class _ChartWidgetState extends State<ChartWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Chart(dataSet: dataSet, dataRec: dataRec);
  }
}

class Chart extends StatefulWidget {
  Map<DateTime, double> dataRec = {};
  Map<DateTime, double> dataSet = {};

  Chart({this.dataRec, this.dataSet});

  @override
  _ChartState createState() => _ChartState();
}

class _ChartState extends State<Chart> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    LineChart chart;
    chart = LineChart.fromDateTimeMaps([dataRec, dataSet],
        [Colors.green, Colors.blue], ['C', 'C']);

    return Container(
        child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: AnimatedLineChart(
        chart,
        key: UniqueKey(),
      ), //Unique key to force animations
    ));
  }
}
```